# is there any way to keep the month same?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, date, input

I have a condition in laravel where I have to put a min date on html input type date but the condition is complex.
**Condition :**
1 : User should only be able to select date from past ten days.
2 : Only two days from previous month. Example lets today date is 4 april then the user should
only be able to select from 4 april to down 1 april and 2 days previous month.

so I can put the min="some date" in input of date

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you actually set the date, but here is a PHP version that should get you closer. All you need to do is extract the parts you need from `$minDate`.

```php
$lastTwo = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-1') . ' -2 days')));
$lastTen = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')));

$minDate = max($lastTen, $lastTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Carbon::now()->month;` to get current month and make conditon according to your query.